# \pinlabel {$r=6$} at 600 450, how is the position 600 and 450?

Tags: graphics

You will notice that the cursor position is recorded (in PS points) either at the bottom or the side. This position is what you will read as your
labelling coordinates.

But I do not know what its meaning.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help others to help you by providing a [complete but minimal example document](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that reproduces the problem you encounter.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `pinlabel` package we need to be able to easily
provide x,y-coordinate values such as

```
\pinlabel {$$} [] at XXX YYY
```

Where XXX YYY are the coordinates as found using **Ghostgum GSView 5** or any other suitable viewer that measures units in points for X and Y values offset from a bottom left origin.

Note that many other graphics packages count either pixels or points from top left.

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
\pinlabel $S^3$ [bl] at 253 283
```

Note that an A4/letter PDF page is very roughly 600 wide by 800 pts high
but images can be any size.

[image: ![enter image description here]

"You will notice that the cursor position is recorded (in PS points)
either **at the bottom** or the side.
This position is what you will read as your labelling coordinates."

600,450 could normally be halfway up a full page on the right hand side
however it could at the top right corner of a 450 pts high image.

It is thus useful to know the total size as well as the coordinates.